# apollo-server-micro: response is missing header 'access-control-allow-methods: POST'

Tags: next.js, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-server

In my `next.js` app I am trying to configure the Apollo Endpoint:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from "apollo-server-micro";

// This data will be returned by our test endpoint. Not sure if I need id? https://apuyou.io/blog/serverless-graphql-apollo-server-nextjs
const tacos = {
  meat: [
    {
      type: 'Al Pastor',
      imgURL: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/190130-tacos-al-pastor-horizontal-1-1549571422.png?crop=0.668xw:1.00xh;0.175xw,0&resize=480:*'
    },
    {
      type: 'Barbacoa',
      imgURL: 'https://i2.wp.com/www.downshiftology.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Barbacoa-Tacos-3.jpg'
    },
    {
      type: 'Chorizo',
      imgURL: 'https://www.seriouseats.com/thmb/-8LIIIObcZMUBy-9gXlMsHcaeMI=/610x458/filters:fill(auto,1)/__opt__aboutcom__coeus__resources__content_migration__serious_eats__seriouseats.com__recipes__images__2014__04__20140428-sloppy-joe-chorizo-taco-recipe-food-lab-lite-8-503212a07b0a4d499952ff40aed57694.jpg'
    },
  ],
  fish: [
    {
      type: 'Camaron',
      imgURL: 'https://juegoscocinarpasteleria.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/1563435179_315_Tacos-De-Camarones-Con-Crema-De-Cal-Y-Cilantro.jpg'
    },
    {
      type: 'Salmon',
      imgURL: 'https://www.cookingclassy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/salmon-tacos-with-avocado-salsa4-srgb..jpg'
    },
    {
      type: 'Pulpo',
      imgURL: 'https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5710a8b3e707ebb8c58fea2c/1590075315244-QNXQE1LGPH06HV3EDF6B/tacos_34.jpg?format=1000w'
    },
  ],
  veggi: [
    {
      type: 'Cauliflower',
      imgURL: 'https://minimalistbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/DELICIOUS-Roasted-Cauliflower-Tacos-with-Adobo-Romesco-30-min-healthy-SO-flavorful-vegan-glutenfree-plantbased-cauliflower-tacos-recipe-8.jpg'
    },
    {
      type: 'Avocado',
      imgURL: 'https://www.ambitiouskitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/tacos.jpg'
    },
    {
      type: 'Tofu',
      imgURL: 'http://www.fromachefskitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Tofu-and-Black-Bean-Tacos.jpg'
    },
  ],
}

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Taco {
    type: String
    imgURL: String
  }

  type Query {
    tacos: [Taco]
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    tacos: () => {
      return tacos;
    },
  },
};

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
module.exports = apolloServer.start().then(() => apolloServer.createHandler({path: '/api/graphql',}));


export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

However, http://localhost:3000/api/graphql gets me to Apollo Studio Start Page. When I finally get to explorer, I get the error message, that my server can't be reached: `OPTIONS` response is missing header `access-control-allow-methods: POST`. I tried to add cors ApolloServer, but with no success. That is my first time trying to get graphql endpoint work in `Next.js` API, I am pretty lost, what is wrong.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if you solved it already but I had the same issue. Even with the latest update in `next.js` examples docs it still gave me this error. So with a little google searching i solved it like this:

```js
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const startServer = apolloServer.start();

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "https://studio.apollographql.com"
    );
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
    );
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD"
    );
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        res.end();
        return false;
    }

    await startServer;
    await apolloServer.createHandler({
        path: "/api/graphql",
    })(req, res);
}
```

Comment: This is great! Maybe you can do a pull request to the Next.js examples?

Comment: Important to start the server as above and not to do await apolloServer.start() in the handler function.  Mistake I made and got error that included text "Error: called start() with surprising state" as it was trying to start the server with every request.

Answer (score 3):

With help of George Vlassis's answer I post here only needed headers for working Apollo Explorer:

```js
res.setHeader(
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
  'https://studio.apollographql.com',
);
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', ' Content-Type');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Apollo-server-Micro, then you can make use of micro-cors:

```
yarn add micro-cors
```

Then, remember to import micro_cors not micro-cors:

```
import micro_cors from "micro-cors"

const cors = micro_cors({
origin: "https://studio.apollographql.com",
allowCredentials:true,
allowMethods:["GET", "POST","PUT","DELETE"],
allowHeaders:["access-control-allow-credentials","access-control-allow-origin","content-type"]          
})
```

Afterwards, wrap this with function:

```
const handlers= cors(async  function  handlers(req: NextApiRequest, res:   NextApiResponse) {
await startServer

if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.end()
    return false
}

await apolloserver.createHandler({ path: "/api/graphql" })(req, res);
})

export default handlers
```

Comment: This did it for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you diagnose the endpoint by this:

```
npx diagnose-endpoint@1.1.0 --endpoint=http://localhost:3000/api/graphql
```

And get the result as this:

```
Diagnosing http://localhost:3000/api/graphql
⚠️  OPTIONS response is missing header 'access-control-allow-methods: POST'
```

Just set the **api.bodyParser** to **false** and put it as a config constant at the bottom of your graphql server api file like this:

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { gql, ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-micro";
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from "apollo-server-core";

...

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()],
});

const startServer = apolloServer.start();

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
): Promise<void> {
  await startServer;
  await apolloServer.createHandler({
    path: "/api/graphql",
  })(req, res);
}

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@yohanes Awnser almost worked for me!
I had to make some changes to it:

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro';
import { applyMiddleware } from 'graphql-middleware';
import schema from '../../graphql/schema';
import { dataloadersMiddleware } from '../../graphql/loaders/middleware';
import microCors from "micro-cors";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from 'apollo-server-core';
import { RequestHandler } from "micro";

const cors = microCors({ 
  allowMethods: [
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *',
  ],
  allowHeaders: [
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
  ],
  allowCredentials: true,
  origin: "*"
});

const server:ApolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema: applyMiddleware(schema, dataloadersMiddleware),
  playground: {
    endpoint: "/api/graphql",
  },
  persistedQueries: false,
  introspection: true,
  plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()]
} as any);

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const startServer = server.start()

export default cors(async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse):Promise<void> {
  await startServer;
  await server.createHandler({ path: "/api/graphql" })(req, res);
} as RequestHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to notice that Apollo just released the v4 and to be able to use it

`plugins: [ ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true }), ],`

this solves the connection problem. [**Here**](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v3/getting-started) is more detail.